# What does "8.11 Encrypt or sign files into an archive" do?

Tags: disk-encryption, gnupg

I am going through the GnuPG manual and I want to encrypt a folder which, if my laptop was taken by anyone else, noone would be able to get access to for any of my information.  [This](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/index.html#SEC_Contents) man page gives me information I need but I don't understand the 'archive' part.  Is this command suitable for encrypting a directory or what command is?  Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98443/encrypting-files-and-folder-through-terminal

Comment: gnupg does not encrypt directories - you need to create an archive and encrypt that

Comment: If you want to use GPG, yes.

Comment: way too many options to try to list here

Comment: I found a good link [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/183826/how-to-create-an-encrypted-file-container-disk-image-on-a-mac/) for OS X.  Thanks.

Comment: And for other systems [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/195124/how-to-easily-encrypt-files-on-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 1):

OpenPGP encryption is only defined on single files, there is no official way to define something like a folder structure, not to speak of permissions, file owners and other thing one might want to keep when encrypting folders.

The "unix way" in working around this is to create an archive, which is subsequently encrypted, which is explained in the GnuPG manual chapter "8.11 Encrypt or sign files into an archive" you referenced.

`gpg-zip` takes a folder as input, puts it into a tar archive which is finally encrypted, keeping an otherwise similar command line interface GnuPG does. Running `gpg --list-packets` on `gpg-zip`'s output reveals what GnuPG is doing here (I used symmetric encryption here, but it works the same way using public/private key encryption), encrypting `/tmp/foo` while being in `/tmp`:

```
$ gpg-zip --symmetric foo | gpg --list-packets
:symkey enc packet: version 4, cipher 3, s2k 3, hash 10
    salt 640c284b119eb28c, count 102400 (105)
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
:encrypted data packet:
    length: 183
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
:compressed packet: algo=1
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1445875407, name="x.tar",
    raw data: unknown length
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected
```

`x.tar` is the file you would also get as result when decrypting the file manually.

Comment: This is useful, thank you.  Might take some time to understand the command line commands.